# script - extract multiple files

Tags: linux, scripting, tar

I have 30 tgz files like these:

```
live-3.0.10-20101031.tgz
live-3.0.4-20101005.tgz
```

when I extract them it will be extract in to "live" folder.(ie: tar xvzf live-3.0.10-20101031.tgz will extract to "live" folder
I would like to have a small script that will extract all files from oldest to newest to "live" folder. I want new files to be copied over old files 
this is what I did but I'm not if it's good...can you please let me know what you think?

```
#!/bin/bash 
for f in live*.tgz; do
    echo $f
    tar xzvf $f &
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you're missing the ; to separate both commands. Also the `&` is probably not needed, you could use it to parallelize the `tar` invocations but it's likely to do more harm than good if you have more than a couple of files (they will compete for I/O and CPU).

For sorting the file list correctly you can use `sort -V`, which sorts taking into account version numbers (the `*` wildcard on bash or plain `sort` would list version 10 before version 4, as 1<4). This should work:

```
for f in `ls live*.tgz | sort -V`; do echo $f; tar xzvf $f; done
```

Comment: how can I control that the older files will extrac first and last will be the newst file?

Comment: Do you mean to sort by the date on the filename (`20101031` in your first example) or the one the file itself (the one that `ls -l` shows, for example)?

Comment: See the edit, if you mean by version and filename this latest version should work.

Comment: when I try to run for f in `ls live*.tgz | sort -V`; do echo $f; tar xzvf $f; done
I get:sort: invalid option -- V
Try `sort --help' for more information.

Comment: What version of Linux have you got? Perhaps `-V` is a recent extension.

Comment: Linux centos5..

Comment: It's true, CentOS doesn't have it - it must be really recent then. Take a look at @hmontoliu's answer, if you can't use it let me know and I'll find a replacement for this.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, form memory:

```
ls -1rt live*tgz | xargs tar xvf
```

Explanation:

- `ls -1` --> list files in one colum
- `ls -t` --> list files based on modification time (best approach to creation time)
- `ls -r` --> list in reverse order (older first)

Then the list is piped to tar trough xargs so tar takes each file one by one and unpacks them as you wanted, from older to newer.

HTH

Comment: +1, this is the way to go if the creation time can be trusted (that is, versions were actually tarred in the right order - a reasonable assumption by the way).

Comment: this is what I get:tar: live-3.0.10-20101031.tgz: Not found in archive
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Comment: Try this: `ls -1tr live*tgz | xargs -L 1 tar xvf`.

Comment: it looks like it's working now but how can I be sure it really takes all the files and extracting them and not only the first file?

Comment: Add `-t` to the xargs command. With it xargs prints the command line being executed before actually executing it.